# Making a responsive flexbox image containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

trying to make a flexbox containers something like this where I can fill them up with images but not quite sure is flexbox right for this one?

```
<flex-container>
    <flex-item>
      <div1></div1>
      <div1></div1>
    </flex-item>
    <flex-item class="big"></flex-item>
    <flex-item>
      <div1></div1>
      <div1></div1>
      <div1></div1>

    </flex-item>
  </flex-container>
```

```
flex-container {
    display: flex;
  }
  flex-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .big {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  div1 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: black;
  }
  div1 + div1 { margin-top: 10px; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/learn007/7sxLufzp/
I am able to get the boxes and rearrange them with the sizes but not quite sure with the concept on how to apparently have only a box on one-side and boxes with different sizes as below?

Comment: You may find CSS grid helps fit a 2d pattern better. Could you check your link to the fiddle as it isn't working.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for the suggest , initially thought of making flexbox and hiding some  blocks but it is turning out to be quite difficult and I have update my fiddle where i got boxes to paly around .

Comment: Is the pattern that you show the final pattern that you want or is it just a sort of idea and would depend on the image natural sizes?

Comment: @AHaworth that is the pattern i looking to build where i put in fill the container with images not dynamic but want the overall structure

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS grid you can position items relative to the grid - this snippet is based on a 27/15 grid as that seemed to allow the items to rest relative to each other as in the image (I just used a ruler to get the relative sizes and positions).

Of course, positions can be tweaked to get exactly what is wanted.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 27 / 15;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(27, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
  gap: 1vmin;
}

.container>* {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.container>*:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  grid-row: 3 / span 6;
}

.container>*:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 7 / span 10;
  grid-row: 1 / span 7;
}

.container>*:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 17 / span 6;
  grid-row: 3 / span 5;
}

.container>*:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 23 / span 5;
  grid-row: 6 / span 5;
}

.container>*:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 7 / span 5;
  grid-row: 8 / span 5;
}

.container>*:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 12 / span 11;
  grid-row: 8 / span 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```